# Php coding advice

Tags: php, curl, get, fsockopen

I want to transform this code in fsockopen:

```
$z = $_GET['z']; 
$z = str_replace(' ', '%20', $z);
if("$z")
{
$file = file("http://example.com/$z");
}else{
$file = file("http://example.com/main/");
}
$file = @implode("", $file);
$file = str_replace('/main/', '?z=main/', $file);
echo $file;
```

can u help me ?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to enable clean URLs rather than a query string?

Comment: The problem is not your English, but the lack of your visits in the elementary school

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
function replaceDomain($url = null){
    $parts = explode('.com/', $url);
    return $parts[0].'.com/index.php?z='.$parts[1];
}

$url = "http://example.com/downloads/programs/100";
echo replaceDomain($url);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
http://example.com/index.php?z=downloads/programs/100
```